# How to give an object created by me a height property so when added to listbox it automatically takes that height?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, height, dependency-properties

I am trying to give height property to an object I created so when I add it to a `ListBox`, the `ListBox` gets that height and it occupies the height I need it to occupy.
Thanks

```
public class mmrequisicion : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightProperty;
    public double Height
    {
        //get
        //{
        //    return 23;//(double)GetValue(HeightProperty);
        //}
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeightProperty, 23);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DataTemplate or ItemTemplate and bind the height property of your container to the Height property of 'mmrequisicion'.